# Getting Started with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded the latest Eclipse CDT release (Helios) and wanted to try my luck with some C++ programming (haven't done that in ages).

I tried to do the "Hello World" project, but I got stuck quite fast.
First thing - the `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` got marked with an 'Unresolved Symbol' warning. So I found the place where I can add include paths and pointed it to these headers from the Visual Studio installation I have.

After that, it looked fine but:

1. I don't see compilation errors/warnings in the **Problems** tab.
2. I cannot run the code - I get 'Launch failed. Binary not found' error

My question is simple - what are the steps I **really** need to do to get my code compiled, linked and executed?
I tried looking for it on Eclipse's site, but didn't find any reference to that.

Comment: I do believe Eclipse does not comes with a toolchain for C++, thus you need to install by hand some compiler toolchain. I know it works well with GCC and MingW on Windows. I don't know of other compilers...

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a guess here, that your are running on Windows, because that particular error seems to be a windows related one.

You seem to be missing the basic toolchain needed by the CDT to actually build the project. You need some files [Before You Get Started](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm). I suggest the mingw installer, as it is simple, and lets you actually build Windows compatible binaries.

Check out the link above, and then make sure your project links to the toolchain. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point could be:

- File -> New -> c++ project
- Type a name for the project, select `Hello World c++ Project` under `Project Type` and click `Finish`.
- Right click on the project -> Run As -> Local C++ application (or just click the `Run` button on the toolbar).

Comment: This is what I have done, my problem is that compilation is not happening, therefore no linkage either. Therefore there is nothing to execute

Comment: If you right click the project, then "Clean Project", then again right click -> build configurations -> build -> all, what do you see in the console (window -> show view -> console)?

Comment: OK, now I'm getting somewhere - I'm getting all sorts of problems. 1st - it is unable to find `make` - so i defined it directly to a make.exe I have on my PC. 
Now it started failing with:
`**** Build of configuration Default for project Proj1 ****  
  
c:\Utils\C++\make all   
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o Proj1.o Proj1.cpp  
g++: installation problem, cannot exec 'cpp0': No such file or   directory  
c:\Utils\C++\make: *** [Proj1.o] Error 1`

Comment: It seems like the makefile it generated is not including all the source files, just the OBJs.
Can someone explain in short what sort of abilities the CDT offers?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with using Eclipse on windows (and cygwin? I assume), only on Unix, but I think there are some posts here dealing with such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error until I ran the "Build All" command. That command created two new  folders, Debug and Release. Then when I clicked the "Debug" button, it asked me which one I wanted to run and I selected "Debug" and it ran perfectly.

It seems like the binary it couldn't find was created from the "Build All" command.